# django-polymorphic Filter by child type

Tags: django, polymorphism, django-polymorphic

I have models structure like below:

```
class MyObject(PolymorphicModel):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class Group(PolymorphicModel):
    pass

class SpecialGroup(Group):
    pass
```

Now, I would like to select all MyObjects, which group is of type SpecialGroup.

Is it possible to achieve it with QuerySet API, without running raw SQL?
The only working solution I came up with was by running additional 'select' SQL query using .extra().

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Internally, django_polymorphic uses Django's ContentType framework to determine the actual class used for each model.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

MyObject.objects.filter(group__polymorphic_ctype=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(SpecialGroup))
```

Comment: I think `MyObject.objects.filter(group__specialgroup__isnull=False)` might work as well