# How do I filter based on instance type when using Django-Polymorphic package?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.11, django-polymorphic

I'm a bit stuck on having to create a Django query to filter based on instance type when using django-polymorphic.

```
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel

class ClassA(models.Model):
    project = select2.fields.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="class_a")
    some_value = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

class Project(PolymorphicModel):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ArtProject(Project):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ResearchProject(Project):
    supervisor = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

How do I go about filtering ClassA objects where its' project is a "ArtProject"?

ClassA.objects.filter( ...? ).update(some_value=0.0)

I've tried breaking it up by going:

```
art_set = ArtProject.objects.all().values_list("project__id", flat=True)
ClassA.objects.filter(id__in=art_set).update(some_value=0.0)
```

Error: "You can't specify target table 'ClassA' for update in FROM clause"

I might be able to use but I'm trying to filter on a related class... I'm not sure if this is in the right direction...
https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced.html#using-enhanced-q-objects-in-any-places

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I can perform the following:

```
art_set = ArtProject.objects.all()
ClassA.objects.filter(project__in=art_set).update(some_value=0.0)
```

However, the translated SQL statement will be very long if the ArtProjects had many entries. I'm not sure if I should avoid the "in" statement when ArtProjects is thousands of entries long.

I was looking into the Q statements but I'm not sure how to use it in this case.
https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced.html#using-enhanced-q-objects-in-any-places

```
Q2 = Projects.translate(Q(project__instance_of=ArtProject))
ClassA.objects.filter(Q2).update(some_value=0.0)
```

However, I get raised an exception: ('Related Field got invalid lookup: instance_of',)

Comment: maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/22675773/2484882

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are two ways of doing this:

**1st Method:**

```
art_set = ArtProject.objects.all()
ClassA.objects.filter(project__in=art_set).update(some_value=0.0)
```

**2nd Method:**

```
ClassA.objects.filter(project__artproject__isnull=False).update(some_value=0.0)
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else who runs into a similar issue!
Cheers,